# How can I choose one item from every list, making every possible combination?

Tags: python, list, python-itertools, sublist

I have input like:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]
```

I want to choose one item from each sublist of a list, and - maintaining order - make every possible combination with them, like:

```
[[1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,1,3],[1,1,4],[1,1,5],[1,2,1]...]
```

Each sub-list in the output should include one item from *each* input sub-list - i.e.: it does not include `[5,5,5]` or `[4,4,5]`, because the first input sub-list does not include `4`, and only the last includes `5`. Order matters: the output should include `[3,4,5]`, but not `[5,4,3]`.

How can I get an exhaustive list of results meeting these criteria? I was hoping there would be an `itertools` function for this, but I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you want [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
[p for p in itertools.product(*x)]
```